# SSIS Compare Flat File Value to SQL Server Lookup Table Min Max Values to find Value

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup

In SSIS I'm trying to compare a flat file value against a SQL Server table with multiple rows with min max number values to return a final value.

I tried using a Lookup but the flat file value must match a corresponding value in the SQL Server table.

I need to be able to compare like flat file value > min and flat file value < max to find row with return value.

Need help with best approach here - thanks.

Comment: Can you help me understand why the lookup won't work here? Perhaps sample data for your flat file source, target table and how you envision the comparison logic working would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of ways of doing this

One way could be to insert the FF data into a global temp (pending the size of data) then comparing the values (flat file value > min and flat file value < max) taking the relation between data sets into consideration (joining the two)